# Rotation in snake game using Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am learning javascript and making a snake game. I am stuck with rotation. The rotation happens on the whole snake element which is the exact thing I am doing and it looks very bad and I am lost of ideas that makes the animation look good.

code:

```js
let direction = 'right';
let snakearray = [1,2,3];

window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
  
    switch (event.key) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        if(direction === 'up')
        {
            return;
        }
        direction = 'down'
        rotateSnake(direction);
        break;
      case "ArrowUp":
        if(direction === 'down')
        {
            return;
        }
        direction = 'up'
        rotateSnake(direction);
        break;
      case "ArrowLeft":
        if(direction === 'right')
        {
            return;
        }
        direction = 'left';
        rotateSnake(direction);
        break;
      case "ArrowRight":
        if(direction === 'left')
        {
            return;
        }
        direction = 'right'
        rotateSnake(direction);
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  
    event.preventDefault();
  }, true);



move = function (direction, distance) {

    let topOrleft = direction == 'left' || direction == 'right' ? 'left' : 'top';

    let snake = document.getElementById('snake');
  
    if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'up') {
      distance *= -1;
    }
    let snakeBoundingRect = snake.getBoundingClientRect();
    let snakeCurrentCoordinates = direction === 'left' || direction === 'right' ? snakeBoundingRect.left : snakeBoundingRect.top;
    snake.style[topOrleft] = (snakeCurrentCoordinates + distance) + 'px';
  
  }


drawSnake = function()
{
  for (let index = 0; index < snakearray.length; index++) {
   
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    let snake = document.getElementById('snake');
    span.style.left = 0 + (index * -16) + 'px';
    span.style.top = '0px';
    span.classList.add('square');
    span.id = 'id-' + (index + 1);
    snake.appendChild(span);
    snake.style.position = 'absolute';
  }
}

rotateSnake = function(direction)
{
    let snake = document.getElementById('snake');
    let snakenodes = document.getElementById('snake').childNodes;
    console.log(snakenodes);
    let rotation = null;
    switch(direction)
    {
        case 'down':
            rotation = 'rotate(90deg)';
            break;
        case 'up':
            rotation = 'rotate(270deg)';
            break;
        case 'left':
            rotation = 'rotate(180deg)';
            break;
        case 'right':
            rotation = 'rotate(0deg)';
            break;
    }
    snake.style.transform = rotation;  
}


drawSnake();
let moveInterval = setInterval(() => move(direction, 5), 1000 / 5);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Snake Movements</title>
    <style>
        .square {
            position: absolute;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="snake"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

help me with the rotation of the snake with code explanation, thank you.

Comment: Your code should be in a single snippet, not three.

Comment: ahh okay will edit it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to rotate whole snake, i think that is a bad idea, you need to rotate each of pieces.

```
function dibujar() {
        let apple = new Apple(Math.random(),Math.random());
        console.log('Aples '+apple.position.x);

        if (contador === snake.size) {
            snake.body.splice(0, 1);
            contador = snake.size - 1;
        }
        if (contador < snake.size) {
            contador++;

            if (direccion === 0) {
                y += -10;
                snake.move(x, y);
            }
            if (direccion === 1) {
                x += 10;
                snake.move(x, y);
            }
            if (direccion === 2) {
                y += 10;
                snake.move(x, y);
            }
            if (direccion === 3) {
                x += -10;
                snake.move(x, y);
            }
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = pat;
        ctx.fillRect(area.x1, area.y1, area.x2, area.y2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,100,0)";
        ctx.beginPath();

        area.paintTerrain(ctx, area.x2, area.y2, "rgb(36,23,23)");
        ctx.fillRect(apple.position.x,apple.position.y,10,10);
        for (let i = 0; i < snake.body.length; i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(snake.body[i].x, snake.body[i].y, x2/50, y2/50);
        }

    }




    move(stepX, stepY) {
            let paso = {};
            paso.x = stepX;
            paso.y = stepY;
            this.body.push(paso);
        }
```